# RecyclerView and Toolbar, can't scroll bottom item into view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

**EDIT:** See [Using the Master/Detail template in ViewPager Fragments (download link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893187/using-the-master-detail-template-in-viewpager-fragments-download-link) for full code

I have a toolbar and a `recyclerView`. When the layout is first inflated the last item of the `recyclerView` is out of the scroll-able region of the screen and is therefore not visible. After rotating the item appears. It is apparent that the toolbar is pushing the `recyclerView` outside the boundaries of the screen. If I add padding to the bottom of the `recyclerView` with the height of the toolbar the issue is resolved BUT only for the initial inflation of the layout. After rotation I am left with a gap on the bottom of the screen. I'm using sdk 23.

A possible workaround would be to programmatically remove the padding after the very first inflation of the layout. I assume I could use:

```
onCreateView(){ if (onSaveInstanceState != null) removePadding();}
```

However, I'd rather not have to do a dodgy work-around.

My app is basically exactly the same as the Master/Detail-flow template supplied in Android Studio, except that I use fragments and a single Activity. There is no such issue in the template.

Any ideas?

fragment_item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:name="com.idragonit.scrolltabs.ItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context="com.idragonit.scrolltabs.ItemListActivity"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_content" />
```

item_list_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
</LinearLayout>
```

snippet of ItemListFragment.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("List");
```

Comment: Why is your behavior on the FrameLayout and not on the RecyclerView?

Comment: Does your Toolbar collapse when you scroll the RecyclerView?

Comment: No. The toolbar is fixed. There is only the toolbar. http://i67.tinypic.com/o0sdhs.png

Comment: After only removing this line http://tinypic.com/r/33acpzo/9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893187/using-the-master-detail-template-in-viewpager-fragments-download-link See for my full code

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

to item_list.xml. The issue persists. The first time the layout is inflated it shows the bottom element as expected. After rotating to landscape and back to portrait it leaves a margin the size of the actionBar at the bottom of the screen.

This issue does not happen in the Master/Detail-flow template available in Android Studio and the code for item_list.xml, item_list_twopane.xml and activity_item_list are exactly the same as the code used in item_list.xml, land/item_list.xml and fragment_item_list.xml in my project. Yet, as the attached images show, the preview of the AppBar shows the flexible space in the Android template but not my code.

EDIT: When I click on the reference for "?attr/actionBarSize" in the template it navigates to a different line in android SDK's values.xml, which starts with `<declare-styleable name="AppCompatTheme">`. The same line of code in my app references a different line starting with`<declare-styleable name="Theme">`.

Screenshots:
[image: My App]
[image: Android Template]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
   xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/white"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
         app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


   </LinearLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain the changes please?

Answer (score 0):

You must add

`android:layout_paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize`

Instead of

`android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize`

This works for me