# How to resolve Soft keyboard Show/hide working slow?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-softkeyboard, android-nestedscrollview

i have use Edittext in ViewPager>Fragment>NestedScrollView>RecyclerView>Edittext

when i show/hide keyboard it take too many time to show/hide and also show me white  background. i all things use like AdjustResize,AdjustPan

[image]

after close keyboard show white background like bellow

[image]

please help me for resolve this issues

Comment: what you have tried to show/hide keyboard

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code that you have used for show/hide the soft keyboard?

Comment: i have not write any code for hide show by default hide and show using backpress key

Comment: I also try this solution not working for me.i have the same issue..help me

Comment: Is your device performant or not ?

Comment: in all device working slow

Comment: Try using the android profiler, to see where the bad performance could be comming from.

Answer (score 3):

I think this performance issue is due to complex hierarchy of your screen.
Try to set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing".

If glitch will gone try to simplify hierarchy

For example in 
ViewPager>Fragment>**NestedScrollView**>RecyclerView>Edittext

Remove NestedScrollView (reuse RecyclerView behaviour or use Airbnb Epoxy library)

PS: also check what application not perform heavy tasks when you focus this field

Answer (score 0):

Hide soft keyboard.
@param callingActivity the calling activity

```
 fun hideSoftKeyboard(callingActivity: Activity) {
        if (callingActivity.currentFocus != null) {
            val inputManager = callingActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(callingActivity
                    .currentFocus!!.windowToken,
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For hide soft keyboard

```
fun hideKeyboard(view: View?) {
        if (view != null) {
            val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
```

for show soft keyboard

```
fun showKeyboard(activity: Activity, editText: View) {
        val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into your code, it's hard to say what could be causing the performance issue. But I see you display image in view pager. Creating bitmap is CPU and memory intensive task. I guess when you open the `ViewPager`, the keyboard opens up at the same time as creating bitmap. Try to disable the keyboard on first activity start. Only start when `EditText` gains focus and also try to cache created `Bitmaps` to some extent to save some CPU cycles. [Here is the official guide for this.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap). While loading bitmaps, we also need to care the size of the `Bitmap` we are loading in memory as compared to the `ImageView` size. If we load large bitmap than the `ImageView`'s bound, definitely it is waste of resources. See [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap). It is always advisable to use any image loading library to do all the heavy lifting. Here is one such library I've been using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

For leaving the white background, check the `ViewPager` height is `match-parent` or `match-constraint`. I also had a problem similar to this in `RecyclerView`, I solved this as mentioned here [RecyclerView drawing offscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978217/recyclerview-drawing-offscreen-cant-scroll-bottom-item-into-view/47018035#47018035)

```
 val obs = pager?.viewTreeObserver
           obs?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                    recyclerView?.requestLayout()
                    recyclerView?.invalidate()
           }
```